# Uses of the Helmert matrix

Tags: data-transformation, matrix, orthogonal

In chapter 8 of "Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective",  the author describes the construction of an orthogonal matrix,  the first row of which is proportional to some row vector of non-zero entries.
Try as I might,  I cannot find anything related to this matrix,  only the so-called Helmert transformation on Wikipedia.

Does anybody know in which areas of statistics such matrices are encountered?

Comment: If I recall correctly they can be used to prove that $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ from iid normal data are independent

Comment: I describe one use of Helmert matrices at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259223/919 (and reference the same text you do).  A much more common and well-known use is in constructing [orthogonal contrasts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=orthogonal+contrast+helmert).  The link identifies many posts on our site concerning this use of Helmert matrices--perhaps one or more therefore directly answer your question?