# Machine Learning Classification with Variables Summing to One

Tags: machine-learning, classification, compositional-data, restrictions

Suppose you have data with a bunch of predictors, and some of these predictors are proportions that add up to one. An example would be data like the following

```
gender  perc_shop   perc_game perc_stud   age
M       .23         .71       .06         31
F       .47         0         .53         19
F       .05         .31       .64         29
```

The variables in columns 2-4 all add up to one, so in logistic regression it would be necessary to remove one as a baseline variable. However, in building a classification model using machine learning methods (i.e. decision trees, random forests, svm, etc.) would it be necessary to remove one of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Compositional data has the quality that the sum of the columns is 1. In a *regression* setting (e.g. OLS, logistic regression), this can cause problems because when the design matrix includes an intercept, it is not full-rank. As a result, the model is not identified and there are arbitrarily many solutions of equal quality. Dropping the intercept or one of the proportion columns, or employing [regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization) such as [ridge](/questions/tagged/ridge) regression, are some solutions.

None of the listed methods (decision trees, random forest, SVM) require a full-rank design matrix to be estimated. SVMs act on the kernel matrix, while decision trees simply seek out good splits.

For tree-based models, dropping a redundant column can cause side-effects, such as causing the model to seek out deeper trees. This answer discusses an example in the context of gradient-boosted trees [One hot encoding of a binary feature when using XGBoost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438875/one-hot-encoding-of-a-binary-feature-when-using-xgboost/439191#439191)

It can be desirable to transform the composition data to a new representation. Here's a discussion. [How to perform isometric log-ratio transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259208)