# One hot encoding of a binary feature when using XGBoost

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, data-mining, boosting

I already asked this question is SO; however, I realized that this may be a better place for this type of question.

I am well aware that when using categorical features with tree based models such as random forest and gradient boosting there is no need to drop one level from N-level categorical features. For example, the following color feature with three levels can be made three binary features.

```
Color|| Color_R | Color_B | Color_G
____ ||_________|_________|________
 R   ||   1     |   0     |   0
 B   ||   0     |   1     |   0
 G   ||   0     |   0     |   1
```

However, what about binary feature (E.g., TRUE/FALSE, MALE/FEMALE)? Should it be kept as a single binary feature (Option I below) or should it also be one-hot encoded into two binary features (Option II below)

**Option I**

```
Gender || Gender  | 
____   ||_________|
M      ||   1     | 
F      ||   0     | 
M      ||   1     |
```

**Option II**

```
Gender || Gender_M | Gender_F 
____   || _________|_________
M      ||    1     |   0     
F      ||    0     |   1     
M      ||    1     |   0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's true that you're not missing information when you use only $k-1$ categories. In linear models, we are all familiar with the dummy variable trap and the relationship between a model with $k-1$ levels and an intercept and a model with $k$ levels and no intercept. *However*, you're using a **tree-based** model, so the mechanics of how recursive binary splits work are important!

In the case of a factor with 2 levels, e.g. "red" and "blue", it's obvious that using the $k-1$ 1hot method is equivalent to choosing the $k$ 1-hot method. This is because `NOT blue` implies `red`. In this case, there is no difference.

But  for $k>2$ categories, you'll need $k-1$ binary splits to isolate the the omitted level (the $k$th level). So if you have 3 levels, e.g. "red", "green", "blue", but you only include 1-hot features for "red" and "green", it will take 2 successive splits to isolate the "blue" samples. This is because if you split on "red", the children are nodes for `red` and `NOT red = green OR blue`. To isolate "blue" when the category "blue" is omitted from the coding scheme, you'll have to split again on "green" because then the children nodes of `green OR blue` will be `blue` and `green`.

As $k$ increases, this problem becomes more pronounced, as you'll require more splits. This may interact with your other hyperparameters in strange ways, because specifying a maximum tree  depth is a common strategy to avoid overfitting with boosted trees/`xgboost`.

If isolating category $k$ isn't important, then this effect may not matter at all for your problem. But if category $k$ *is* important, you'll tend to grow very deep trees to try and isolate it, either via the categorical variables or else by identifying latent interactions of other variables.

Comment: (+1) I hadn't thought of the class isolation problem before!

Answer (score 1):

Go with your **Option I** - there is no need to do one-hot encoding when there are only two categories. 
 These two columns `Gender_M` and `Gender_F` carry the exact same information (since it's binary, at least in your example).
I think some frameworks need binary *classes* to be one-hot encoded, but not features.

Comment: Itamar, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Just to be clear, what you are suggestion for non-linear models (e.g., DT) is that for categorical feature with k levels where k>2 ( e.g., the color feature where k=3) then create k features. But when k=2 (e.g., Gender feature, k=2) then use k-1 levels. Correct? But what will happen if the binary feature is missing? In this case a value of 0 doesn't indicate missing value the same as if a values of [0,0,0] would have indicated a missing value for the color feature.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but for future readers: When choosing whether to encode binary categories as one or two binary features, the answer does not depend on the handling of missing values.Missing value handling can be done in a lot of different ways (e.g. dropping, imputing), and just passing 0 to each of the one-hot-encoded features might not be the best way to handle that (unless "missing" in your problem explicitly means "other", in which case this is appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

I had same doubt on this matter. When you have K = 2 (just like in gender case) you will end up having 100% multicollinearity with other value anyway (GenderMale = GenderFemale in terms of collinearity) so it makes sense to drop one of them. Since tree models can handle multicollinearity, you do not necessarily have to drop when K > 2. However, when K = 2, even if tree models can well handle multicollinearity, you should still drop one of the values as it leads to perfect multicollinearity. This is how I see it.

Comment: However, based on another recent post (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80296/dropping-one-category-for-regularized-linear-models) for regularized regression you should not drop one category.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64377627/9215780):

> Converting a binary variable into a one-hot encoded one is redundant
> and may lead to troubles that are needless and unsolicited. Although
> correlated features may not always worsen your model, yet they will
> not always improve it either.