# Standardizing Percentages and raw data

Tags: k-means, standardization, hierarchical-clustering

Apologies for what looks like a easy question but i'm a doing a geodemogrpahic classification and i'm about to run my cluster analysis. Most of my data is in percentages (ie %black,white,asian etc) but I do have some raw totals in there. so would my standardisation method (zscore) work on both my percentages and totals to put them on the same scale or do I need to convert them totals and other raw numbers to percentages to make them equally comparable.

Comment: Depending on your objectives and what the clustering is intended to represent, you might find that the generalized ILR described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259208 can be a very effective way to re-express the percentage variables.