# Looking for advice on conceptualizing and modeling this type of data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, anova, modeling, multivariate-analysis

In a hypothetical experiment, lets assume that there are 30 lakes and I suspect that there is a difference in their chemistry. To test this, I randomly sample 10 rocks from each lake and measure the concentration of 7 elements (lets say the elements are Ca, Co, Cu, Mg, Mn, Zn, and Pb) in a single location on each rock (the same size spot on every rock. My goal is to see if there is a difference between these lakes based on these 7 elements, and see which lakes are different based on what elements. So I collect my data, and my data set is structured like this:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
   ID = seq(300),
   Lake = paste0("Lake", 1:30),
   Ca = rnorm(300, 1,3),
   Co = rnorm(300, 3,4),
   Cu = rnorm(300, 2,2),
   Mg = rnorm(300, 0,2),
   Mn = rnorm(300, 0,1),
   Zn = rnorm(300, 2,1),
   Pb = rnorm(300, 0.5,3)
)
```

Where `ID` is a unique identifier for each rock that was sampled, `Lake` is the lake the rock was sampled from, and the concentration of each element is recorded in each respective column.

My interpretation of the experimental design:
I have one categorical (discrete) independent variable (or explanatory or predictor variable if you like) which is: `Lake`. 
   - `Lake` has 30 levels (`Lake1:Lake30`), because 30 lakes were sampled. 
   - Each lake has 10 random samples 
I have 7 continuous response/dependent variables (each element that was measured)

I have a few specific questions, and would like some advise on how I should approach modeling and analyzing this data.

1. Assume that the sampling method used to obtain the 10 rocks from each lake was completely random. Sampling one rock had no influence on the sampling of another rock, and the concentration of the measured elements in one rock had no influence on the concentration of elements in other rocks (some may wish to dispute that but for this example assume it is true, for this example pretend the chemistry of the rock depends on the water and not the other way around). My question is: analytically, can I treat the individual rocks from each lake as independent samples, or do I have to consider this a nested design? If my goal is to see if there is a difference between lakes, can I just analyze each element with a one way anova, or do I have to use a nested anova?
2. If I didn't have exactly 10 rocks for each lake, say some lakes only had 7, and some had 11 or 12 (numbers relatively close to 10), does this immediately make my design unbalance? Would I need to switch from a type 1 anova?
3. If I wanted to approach this by comparing all 7 elements across lakes at once, and even see which elements were important in differentiating each lake, how would I approach modeling that? My first thought is to use PCA on the 10 members of each individual lake. That could tell me something about which elements were important to each lake, but I don't think it would make intuitive sense to compare eigenvectors across lakes (to see if the lakes are different) if they are influenced unevenly by different variables? Is there a more regressive type modeling approach that I could use to describe these patterns? How would I address this in any multivariate way with a discrete categorical predictor?

for reference, my general idea of approaching this is to do this process for every element:

```
hist(data$Ca) #looks normal
mod1 <- lm(Ca~Lake, data=data) 
summary(mod1)
plot(mod1) #looks homoscedastic
Ca.aov <- aov(Ca~Lake, data=data) #because TukeyHSD doesn't seem to like lm()
Ca.aov
Tky.Ca <- TukeyHSD(Ca.aov)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompLetters)
multcompLetters(extract_p(Tky.Ca$Lake) #no diffs in Ca
```

Beyond answers to the specific questions, any thoughts, ideas or comments would be welcome and appreciated

Comment: 1) What would you nest? 2) ANOVA does not require equal sample sizes. What do you see as your experimental design? The small number of rocks in the lake might be concerning, but this strikes me as a simple random sample. 3) This is multivariate analysis of variance: MANOVA. It does ANOVA but on mean vectors.

Comment: What was the reason for not collecting ten rocks from each lake?  The concern is that inaccessibility of geological samples very well could be related to their geological composition.  BTW, [PCA on the Box-Cox generalization of the ILR of *all* the data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259208) is an attractive exploratory approach, even though with these trace elements it's unnecessary to view them as compositional data.