# Can I use compositional data in a GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, multicollinearity, compositional-data

I have landing data (kg) of five species where I try to identify which factors may be contributing most strongly to the high catch. Before, I had 4 predictor variables (Depth, Chlorophyll, Temperature and Bottom Type), the last one was a categorical variable with 17 levels, which was making it very difficult to interpret the results.

Because of that, I reduced the levels to just 4 variables, totaling 7 predictor variables (Depth, Chlorophyll, Temperature, Reef, Rhodolith, Seamount Slope and Unconsolidated). I transformed the 4 new variables into % and then in sine arc to further dilute the effects of the 0, and thus, being numerical, it could be easier to interpret the results. However, I am unsure if there is any problem with using compositional data in glm along with other continuous data.

In the VIF test there was a high collinearity but I saw a discussion where they said that it would be too much noise for nothing since the problem of multicollinearity is not statistical, but of a substantive nature and that I should not worry about it until the correlation is greater than 95, which means I'm using almost the same information twice. I have vif = 36 for two compositional variables in one model. I saw that one option would be to remove one of the variables, but I believe that it would not be feasible to remove any variable from the model considering my objective.

Note: I am using the Gaussian family and used the box-cox transformation to normalize my dependent variable (`cpue`). Here is my model:

```r
glm(CPUE ~ Depth + Chlorophyll + SST + Reef + Rodolith + SS + Uncons,
    data=chrysurus, family=gaussian)
```

Comment: How did you transform the levels of a categorical variable in %?  I don't quite follow this.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this merits a downvote.

Comment: Would https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259208 ease your misgivings?

Comment: To clarify, is your "bottom type" variable describing the proportion of different bottom types found in the sampling unit relevant to a particular observation?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica As I didn't want the text to be too long, I tried to summarize it. My sample unit is divided into a quadrant within a map. I considered the presence of each of the variables as a 25% contribution, that is, if the four bottom types occurred in the same quadrant, each represents 25% of "importance".

Comment: @BenBolker Yes!

Comment: @whuber yes, it gave me a light. Thanks.