# Log-ratio transformations, Aitchison Geometry, why logs?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, compositional-data

I'm recently diving into the field of *compositional data analysis* and I'm still wondering why the log transformations that Aitchison proposes work.

What I understand is that, having a $D$- part composition $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_d)$ in the $D:=d-1$ dimensional simplex $\mathcal{S}^D$ means having the constraints that $x_1 > 0, \dots, x_d >0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^d x_i = 1$.

So what is the **goal** of using log-ratios-based transformations? I mean, **why** using **logs** and no **other functions**? My intuition suggests because of the beautiful properties that log function manifests, in particular that the **log of ratio is the difference of logs**, but I would like someone to formalize this intuition better.

To my understanding we also use it to modify the constraints specified above..

For example, considering the *additive-log-ratio* transform, we take the log-ratios of each coordinate with respect to a fixed one:

$$alr(\textbf{x}) : \mathcal{S}^D \ni (x_1, \, \dots \, , x_d) \, \mapsto \left[log\frac{x_1}{x_d}, \, \dots \, , log\frac{x_{d-1}}{x_d}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^D $$

So the constraint we have in the simplex at the beginning would become the following:

\begin{align}
x_1+ \dots + x_d = 1 \, \, \, \overset{(?)}{\Rightarrow} \, log\frac{x_1}{x_d} + \dots + log\frac{x_{d-1}}{x_d} = 0
\end{align}

where the right part geometrically describes a hyperplane passing through the origin (even if I'm not sure that it's correct to apply the log function to above equation the way I did to illustrate the change of constraints).

EDIT:

Ok so In case of the $alr(\textbf{x})$ one *totally* removes the constraint going into a $D-1$ dimensional space (but then how can this transformation be described as an isomorphism?).

Instead another constraint gets introduced when one uses the *centred log-ratio* transform:

$$clr(\textbf{x}) : \mathcal{S}^D \ni (x_1, \, \dots \, , x_d) \, \mapsto \left[log\frac{x_1}{g(\textbf{x})}, \, \dots \, , log\frac{x_d}{g(\textbf{x})}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^D $$

with $g(\textbf{x}) = (\Pi_{i=1}^d x_i)^{1/d}$

It's actually using this second transformation that points get mapped to a $D$- dimensional hyperplane passing through the origin. But can anybody explain me better the motivation underlying these transformation using log-functions?

I remember that I've read somewhere that *the log-functions are the only respecting the **scale-invariance principle** at the base of CoDa..

Comment: the transform you list is $\mathcal{S}^D \to \mathbb{R}^{D-1}$, and results in an unconstrained vector (of lower dimension).

Comment: Ok thanks I was messing up a bit with the notation. Anyway I've modified the question with further details

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259223/919, which explains some of the motivation.