# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) the constant sum constraint

Tags: pca, compositional-data

I have data that sums to 100 % +/- 5%, and I was reading that data that sums to 100% should be altered before doing PCA. A method that I found others have done is to use the centered log-ratio (clr) transformation.

I'm not sure if I should do this on my data set, since some samples have a sum of 105%, but an increase in one value causes a decrease in another value, so that the sum is near 100%.

Let me know if anyone has any feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll let others comment, but this seems to me to be a nonstandard case such that trying it both ways and seeing how it influences the results is the only way to proceed.

Comment: Please explain how this constraint arises.  It could make a difference whether there's an underlying sum-to-unity constraint (and this reflects measurement errors) or if there's no actual constraint.  Whether "data ... should be altered" is a matter for investigation, not as a general rule blindly to be followed.  There are some general principles you might find helpful, some of which are followed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259223/919 and are likely applicable to your analyses.